# Binding TextBox.Text to a Property in a class in ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I have two `TextBox`es. I have two `ObservableCollection`s. The `ObservableCollection` has items of the following type:

```
public class ChartData : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    DateTime _Name;
    double _Value;

    #region properties

    public DateTime Name
    {
        get
        {
            return _Name;
        }
        set
        {
            _Name = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Name");
        }
    }

    public double Value
    {
        get
        {
            return _Value;
        }
        set
        {
            _Value = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Value");
        }
    }

    #endregion

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

I need to bind each of the `TextBox.Text` to the Value Property in each of the `ObservableCollection`s. The `ObservableCollection`s are `DataContext` for other controls in the window too. Since I have more than one `ObservableCollection`, I cannot set the `DataContext` to the Window.

New data is added to the `ObservableCollection` using:

```
ObservableCollection<ChartData>lineSeries1Data = new ObservableCollection<ChartData>();
lineSeries1Data.Add(new ChartData() { Name = DateTime.Now, Value = 0.0 });
```

When a new Value is added to the Collection, I want the `TextBox` to show the Value property

Comment: To which item in the collection do you bind each TextBox? A collection apparently can have multiple items. So I do not get the overall concept of your problem. You could just set the DataContext of each specific TextBox to a specific Collection. Maybe you need to explain it a little more...

Comment: I need to bind the TextBox.Text to the Value Property

Comment: I have modified my question.Am I clear?

Comment: May I know how you decide which object in `ObservableCollection` will used for display the value property? And what `container` hold `TextBox`?

Comment: @Alex: I need to show the Value property in the TextBox for every new object added

Comment: do you need to use a twoway-binding on the `TextBox`? Or do you just need to display the Value of the last added object? Big difference...

Comment: I think you may separate property for `TextBox`, and when your `ObservableCollection` have new item added (maybe in setter), then update the property of `TextBox` to new value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this if you don't need a "real" binding, but just need to display the Value of the last object which is added (pseudo code):

```
public string NewItem { get; set+notify; }

ctor(){
    myCollection = new ObservableCollection<T>();
    myCollection.CollectionChanged += OnMyCollectionChanged;
}

private void OnMyCollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs args)
{
    if (args.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add){
        var last = args.NewItems.FirstOrDefault();
        if (last == null) return;
        NewItem = last.Value;
    }
}


//XAML:
<TextBox Text="{Binding NewItem, Mode=OneWay}" />
```